# Data from web api and it's not Display in Html page

Tags: angular

I try to create a simple angular application. I'm trying to get data from web api. Issue is data is come to the front end (console.log(DataObeject).

here is my service.ts

```
     employerApiUrl = 'http://localhost:63858/api/';

    //private url: UrlConst;
    constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    // get all employee list

    getAllEmployee(): Observable<Employer>  {
        return this._httpClient.get<Employer>(this.employerApiUrl + 'Employe/getAllEmploye');
    }
}
```

and here the my componets ts

```
export class EmployerVeiwComponent implements OnInit {

  EmployerList;
  constructor(private _employerDetails: EmployerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployee();
  }

  // getting employee data from service 
  getEmployee() {
    this._employerDetails.getAllEmployee()
      .subscribe(
        employerList => employerList = this.EmployerList);
  }
}
```

an here my html

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Employer ID</th>
        <th>Firs Name</th>
        <th>Last Name <button>&#x2191;</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor = "let employer of EmployerList">
        <td>{{ employer.ID }}</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

here the issue

[image]

here the console result

[image]

It's creating bars in table amount of records coming from API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues

(i) You need to initialize the array as,

```
EmployerList : any =[];
```

(ii)Assign the result to the **`EmployerList`** as,

```
getEmployee() {
    this._employerDetails.getAllEmployee()
      .subscribe(
        employerList => this.EmployerList = employerList );
}
```

(iii) Also it should be **`id`** not **`ID`** in template

```
<tr *ngFor = "let employer of EmployerList">
     <td>{{ employer.id}} : {{employer.fname}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: strange! are you sure you are getting the result? add a console.log(this.EmployerList) and see

Comment: yes. I see the result in the console. Console print all data

Comment: can you post the result here? console.log(JSON.stringify(this.EmployerList));

Comment: I added console result

Comment: name are working. but id is not disply. how I display Id ?

Answer (score -1):

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")  add this in your controller
```